# React useState hook gets typed incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

When I try to use `useState` hook without default value it get's typed incorrectly. It doesn't include `undefined` in possible types. For example in component bellow:

```
type Color = 'blue' | 'yellow' | 'red';


const MyComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState<Color>();

  color.toLocaleLowerCase();

  return null;
};
```

The `color` is typed as `Color` and therefore `color.toLocaleLowerCase()` won't raise any typescript error, even though in reality the `color` can also be undefined (which of course, would cause runtime error).

I even tried specifying the `undefined` explicitly as possible type: `const [color, setColor] = useState<Color | undefined>();` but `color` is still typed just as `Color`.

I am almost sure that this used to work. Did anyone else ran into similar issue?

Some dependencies:

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"expo": "^37.0.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
"@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.8.3",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.28.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.28.0",
"typescript": "^3.8.3",
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "sourceMap": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you not using a default value?

Comment: Because if I am not mistaken `undefined` is the default value if no other value is provided. However even if I try `const [color, setColor] = useState<Color>(undefined);` type of `color` is still just `Color` and not `Color | undefined`.

Comment: but then this is going to break isn't it? `undefined.toLocaleLowerCase();`

Comment: Well it will break in any case during the runtime. I want typescript to catch the error before I actually run the code.

Comment: @RedBaron Accepted answer from Aleksey L. explains what the problem was and how to fix it.

Comment: sure, glad you found this fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `"strictNullChecks": true` in *compilerOptions*

> In strict null checking mode, the `null` and `undefined` values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and `any` (the one exception being that `undefined` is also assignable to `void`). So, whereas `T` and `T | undefined` **are considered synonymous in regular type checking mode** (because `undefined` **is considered a subtype of any** `T`), they are different types in strict type checking mode, and only `T | undefined` permits `undefined` values. The same is true for the relationship of `T` to `T | null`.

More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks).